# Updating react state needs needs two click to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-state

I'm new to react, and I have a basic app that fetch data from an api using `axios`, I'm able to fetch the data and set the state of the component except when using an event click on `div` to update the state it needs two clicks to update the `ayahsAudios` and `ayahsText`, please kindly explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Here is the component code :

```js
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
    import axios from "axios"
    import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
    import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'
    import './QuranPlayer.scss'
    
    const apiBaseUrl = "https://api.quran.gading.dev/surah/"
   
    const QuranPlayer = () => {
    
        const [surahs, setSurahs] = useState([])
        const [ayahsText, setAyahsText] = useState([])
        const [ayahsAudios, setAyahsAudios] = useState([])
    
        let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
        let ayah = document.querySelector('.ayah');
    
        const AlertSwal = withReactContent(Swal)
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(apiBaseUrl)
                .then((response) => { setSurahs(response.data.data) })
  
        }, [])
      
        let ayahIndex = 0
        const handleSurah = async (index) => {

            setAyahsAudios([]);
            setAyahsText([]);
            let data = []
            await axios.get(`${apiBaseUrl}${index + 1}`)
                .then((response) => { data = (response.data.data) })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.toJSON());
                })
            setAyahsAudios(data.verses);
            setAyahsText(data.verses);
 
            changeAyah(ayahIndex)
            audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
                ayahIndex++;
    
                if (ayahIndex < ayahsAudios.length) {
                    changeAyah(ayahIndex);
    
    
                } else if (ayahIndex === ayahsAudios.length) {
                    console.log()
                    AlertSwal.fire(
                        '   إنتهت السورة ',
                        '',
                        'success'
                    )
    
                }
            });
    
        }
        async function changeAyah() {
  
            console.log(audio)
            console.log(ayahsAudios)
            audio.src = await ayahsAudios[ayahIndex].audio.primary;
            ayah.innerHTML = await ayahsText[ayahIndex].text.arab;
     
        }
     
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="player">
                    <div className="ayah">
    
                        إِضغطْ عَلى السُّورة للإستماعِ إليها
                  </div>
                    <audio className="quranPlayer" controls autoPlay></audio>
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <div className="icons next">⏭️</div>
                        <div className="icons play">▶️</div>
                        <div className="icons prev">⏮️</div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
    
                <div className="surahs">
    
                    {
                        surahs.map((data, index) => (
    
                            <div key={index} onClick={() => handleSurah(index)}>
                                <p> {data.name.long}</p>
    
    
                                <p>{data.name.transliteration.en}</p>
                            </div>
    
    
                        ))
                    }
    
    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
        )
    }
    
    export default QuranPlayer
```

the styling :

```scss
    .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
    
    
        .player {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #2e3b4a, #2c3846, #2b3543, #29333f, #27303c, #283543, #293b49, #294050, #285060, #26616e, #277379, #31847f);
            top: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: sticky !important;
            z-index: 2;
    
            .ayah {
                padding: 10px 0;
                font-size: 2rem;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
    
            }
    
            audio {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                margin: 15px 0;
    
    
    
    
            }
    
            .buttons {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
    
    
    
                .icons {
                    width: 60px;
                    height: 60px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    display: grid;
                    place-items: center;
                    color: #313744;
                    font-size: 1.1rem;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        .surahs {
    
            div {
                color: #313744;
                background-color: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                width: calc(100% - 90px);
                transition: .6s color ease-in-out;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                position: relative;
                counter-increment: surah-counter;
    
                &::after {
                    content: counter(surah-counter);
                    position: absolute;
                    height: 80px;
                    width: 80px;
                    left: -90px;
                    top: 50%;
                    transform: translateY(-50%);
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    font-size: inherit;
                    line-height: 80px;
                    text-align: center;
                    transition: inherit;
                    background-color: inherit;
                    box-shadow: inherit;
    
                    &:hover {
                        color: #fff;
                        background-color: 2e3b4a;
                    }
    
                }
    
                &::before {
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute;
                    border: 7px solid transparent;
                    border-right-color: #2e3b4a;
                    top: 50%;
                    transform: translateY(-50%);
                    left: -14px;
                }
    
                &:hover {
    
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #2e3b4a;
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

See here for the complete code [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-water-jti787?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first thing you need to know the structure of each response:

- First thing you get in your first call is 'surahs' you can put is in global state called `surahs`
- Second thing you get after change of each surahIndex is 'surahverces' which is array of verces, you can use the next and prev buttons of the player to play each verce.

So what you need is:

- `surahs` state to hold all the surahs names
- `surahVerces` array state to hold each surah verce
- `currentSurahIndex` state which will hold the current surah that plays and it will change after each click on each surah or after the completion of playing of each surah verces, you can create functions such `handleNext`, `handlePrev` to hand the `currentSurahIndex`

You can create a `VercePlayer` component separately whcih will hold the play and play each verce after a click on `next` `prev`. `Verce

Player`will receive`verces`prop for each`Surah`.` VercePlayer` contains mainly

- `currentVerceIndex` state to play each surah verces (ayats),
- `audioRef` which use [react useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) to keep track of the audio dom element to add the `src` each time we play another verce
- `verceRef` is referece to the surah text dom element that will change after each change of verce

Now logically How to things:

- First load get all surahs => useEffect
- After each click on surah change `currentSurahIndex` => function to handle change
- After each change of `currentSurahIndex` get the `surahVerces` from the api => useEffect
- After each change of `currentVerceIndex` play the audio and change the verce text => useEffect

> Note you can add active state to the div `surah` so the user will notice which surah is currently playing after each click, and you can add upon it whatever else functionalities you want

That is it, I encourage you to read more about useEffect, useState, useRef hooks and when to use each of them from the [react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react) and mostly try to set instruction logically and building things step by step.

Here is how you `QuranPlayer` component should look like approximately

```js
const QuranPlayer = () => {
  const [surahs, setSurahs] = useState([]);
  const [surahVerces, setSurahVerces] = useState([]);
  const [currentSurahIndex, setCurrentSurahIndex] = useState(1);
  const surahRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // get Surah
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // get Surah after change of currentSurahIndex and set surahVerces
  }, [currentSurahIndex]);

  const nextSurah = () => {
    // handle nextSurah
  };

  const prevSurah = () => {
    // handle prevSurah
  };

  const handleCurrentSurahIndex = (number) => {
    // set currentSurahIndex after click on each surah
  };

  const handleSurah = (number) => {
    handleCurrentSurahIndex(number);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <VercePlayer
        verces={surahVerces}
        nextSurah={nextSurah}
        prevSurah={prevSurah}
      />
      <div className="surahs">
        {surahs.map((surah) => (
          /* You can create separate component for Surah to keep things more cleaner*/
          <div
            /*Change the active surah style*/
            className={
              surah.number === currentSurahIndex ? "surah active" : "surah"
            }
            /*key should be set to an id not index to prevent dom issues read more about using significant keys*/
            key={surah.number} 
            ref={surahRef}
            onClick={() => {
              handleSurah(surah.number);
            }}
          >
            <p> {surah.name.long}</p>
            <p>{surah.name.transliteration.en}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is how your `VercePlayer` component should look like; this to separate logic and concerns

```js
...
const VercePlayer = ({ verces, nextSurah, prevSurah }) => {
  const [currentVerceIndex, setCurrentVerceIndex] = useState(0);
  const audioRef = useRef(null);
  const verceRef = useRef(null);
  const handleNext = () => {
    /*Hnadle Next Verce logic*/
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    /*Hnadle Prev Verce logic*/
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentVerceIndex(0);
  }, [verces]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (verces && verces.length > 0) {
      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.src = verces[currentVerceIndex].audio.primary;
      }
      if (verceRef.current) {
        verceRef.current.innerHTML = verces[currentVerceIndex].text.arab;
      }
    }
  }, [currentVerceIndex, verces]);

  return (
    <div className="player">
      <div ref={verceRef} className="ayah">
        إِضغطْ عَلى السُّورة للإستماعِ إليها
      </div>
      <audio ref={audioRef} className="quranPlayer" controls autoPlay></audio>
      <div className="buttons">
        <div className="icons next" onClick={handleNext}>
          ⏭️
        </div>
        <div className="icons play">▶️</div>
        <div className="icons prev" onClick={handlePrev}>
          ⏮️
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

...
```

To see the full code see [this codesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quranplayer-oonb1f)